# Duda sobre API REST para mostrar un array

Tags: javascript, nodejs, rest

¡Buenas! Estoy con una duda acerca de cómo mostrar un array sin el último elemento en una API REST nodejs. Tengo claro que en JS una forma de hacerlo sería:
(Busco la salida 1,2,3,4,5)

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length-1;i++) {
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```

En mi API REST, con mi módulo express instalado y demás, si quiero hacer una petición get de ese mismo array, por más que lo intento me sale la salida del array entero. ¿Alguien podría darme alguna sugerencia?

```js
app.get('/array/', function (req, res) {    
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
        res.json(array[i]);
    }   
});
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

El código:

```
 app.get('/array/', function (req, res) {    
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
            res.json(array[i]);
        }   
    });
```

No servirá, get() necesita obtener un recurso y tú tratas de llenar un arreglo.

Un ejemplo te podría servir.

1. Creas un array de objetos:

`var listaDatos=[];
    var datosA = {"id":"1","concepto":"arroz","importe":13};
    var datosB = {"id":"2","concepto":"manzanas","importe":30};
    var datosC = {"id":"3","concepto":"jabones","importe":20};
    listaDatos.push(datosA);
    listaDatos.push(datosB);
    listaDatos.push(datosC);`

2. Creas una petición GET usando express:

```
var express = require('express');
    var app = express();

    app.get("/datos",function(request,response){
        response.send(listaDatos);
    });
```

3. El listen:

   `var servidor = app.listen(3000,function(){
       console.log("Servidor en puerto 3000");
   });`
4. Ejecutamos el archivo (.js) con:

`node servidor.js`

5. Abres el navegador en http://localhost:3000/datos

Espero te sirva.

**EDITADO:**
Puedes hacer esto:

```
app.get("/array", (req,resp) =>{
  var array = [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3}];
  resp.send(array);
});
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar, pero creo que me expliqué mal. Lo qe quiero es que si yo tengo un array, me devuelva el array menos el último elemento, lo cual es fácil en js, pero ¿en una aplicación rest?

Comment: Emplea la misma lógica para que muestres el array.

Comment: Ya edité la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

En tu respuesta a la petición get estas devolviendo muchas respuestas y esa petición solo puede manejar una.

Genera un subarreglo con los elementos que necesitas y devuelvelos en una sola respuesta, no dentro de un for.

```
res.json(arraySinUltimoElemento);
```

Answer (score 0):

> En mi API REST, con mi módulo express instalado y demás, si quiero hacer una petición get de ese mismo array, por más que lo intento me sale la salida del array entero.

Es lo normal, teniendo en cuenta que la condición de tu bucle `for` es:

```
for (let i=0; i<array.length - 1; i++)
```

Los índices dentro de un array van siempre desde `0` hasta `n - 1`, donde `n` es el número de elementos. Por consiguiente, si el array tiene `5` elementos, estás obteniendo: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`, que viene a ser **todo el array**.

**Soluciones**

Lo que deseas hacer se puede hacer de la forma en la que intentas, pero usando `array.length - 2` como condición:

```
for (let i=0; i<array.length - 2; i++) { ... }
```

También usando el método `Array#splice`:

```
const truncated = array.slice(0, array.length - 1)
```

Y también usando el método `Array#pop`:

```
array.pop() // elimina el último elemento
res.json({ array })
```